# How can I filter by taxonomy on a custom post type's page?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives

Right now I am outputting the related categories to the current displayed post type as shown below. I am using `wp_list_categories` to list out the categories and it works just fine. The only issue is that this is being displayed on archive.php and not a single post, so the Taxonomies that are being listed link to their main taxonomy archive.

I would like to link to the taxonomy archive for the current post type (`$type`) as well as include the query to display that specific taxonomy. Similar to linking to `http://example.com?post_type=foo&custom_tax=bar`

```
<? $type = get_post_type(); ?>
                <?php 

                $customPostTaxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($type);

                if(count($customPostTaxonomies) > 0)
                {
                echo '<h3>Browse By:</h3>';
                     foreach($customPostTaxonomies as $tax)
                     {
                         $args = array(
                              'orderby' => 'name',
                              'show_count' => 0,
                              'pad_counts' => 0,
                              'hierarchical' => 1,
                              'taxonomy' => $tax,
                              'title_li' => ''
                            );
                         $woah = get_taxonomy($tax);
                        echo '<ul>';
                        //var_dump($tax);
                        //var_dump($woah);
                        //print_r($woah);
                        echo '<h4>'.$woah->labels->name.'</h4>';
                        echo wp_list_categories( $args );
                        echo '</ul>';
                     }
                }

                ?>`
```

Comment: I think instead of `wp_list_categories()` you want [Function Reference/get the term list « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list)

Comment: @GhostToast I cannot understand how what you suggest should help.

Comment: I thought wp_list_categories only worked for default category. I was wrong. In that case, I'm not sure why the code above isn't working.

Comment: The code works. OP want only change term link outputted by `wp_list_categories`. He says: _"it works just fine"_ (2nd line) and _"I would like to link to the taxonomy archive for the current post type as well as include the query to display that specific taxonomy"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wp_list_categories` uses `get_term_link` to retrive the terms link.

This function have a filter that you can use to change what is returned.
A problem is that you have to pass the current post type to the function that hooks into the filter, but a global variable should works for the scope.

Of course you have to remove filter after all `wp_list_categories` calls, for not interfere with nex class of `get_term_link`.

So, in your `functions.php` put:

```
function convert_term_link_to_post_type( $termlink, $term, $taxonomy ) {
  global $the_current_type;
  if ( empty($the_current_type) ) return $termlink;
  $link = get_post_type_archive_link( $the_current_type );
  if ( $taxonomy == 'category') $taxonomy = "category_name";
  if ( $link ) return add_query_arg( array($taxonomy => $term->slug), $link );
  return $termlink;
}
```

Then change the code you posted like so:

```
$type = get_post_type();
$customPostTaxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($type);
if( count($customPostTaxonomies) > 0) {
  echo '<h3>Browse By:</h3>';
  // set the global variable
  global $the_current_type;
  $the_current_type = $type;
  // add the filter that convert the term link
  add_filter('term_link', 'convert_term_link_to_post_type', 20, 3);
  foreach($customPostTaxonomies as $tax) {
    $woah = get_taxonomy($tax);
    $args = array(
      'orderby' => 'name',
      'show_count' => 0,
      'pad_counts' => 0,
      'hierarchical' => 1,
      'taxonomy' => $tax,
      'title_li' => ''
    );
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<h4>' . $woah->labels->name . '</h4>';
    echo wp_list_categories( $args );
    echo '</ul>';
  }
  // unset the global variable
  unset($the_current_type);
  // remove the filter to not alter any other 'get_term_link' calls
  remove_filter('term_link', 'convert_term_link_to_post_type', 20, 3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you happen to know how to get `hide_empty` and `show_count` working? They both work, but it's getting the count for all posts and not the current post type.

Comment: I still haven't figured out how to get the proper categories for the current term listed. It shows taxonomy related to the post, but it also shows empty ones which is confusing. I have tried hide_empty but it checks against ALL post types and not just the current one.

Comment: The problems is related to how taxonomy works in WP. When wordpress count for terms it does't distinct among post types. If the taxonomy is shared by more types becomes very hard and poor performant differentiate terms count and/or term existence for post types...

Comment: This helped me a lot! but in my case, i knew the archive and taxonomies i want to change, so i check if the taxonomy is one of the types i want and them change the link